# Get product attributes values for out of stock products in elastic search without changing 'display out of stock' configuration setting to yes

Tags: php, database, magento2.4, elasticsearch

So I want to get product's attribute value to work on if it is set to yes but product is out of stock so it is not shown on the frontend. One solution is to change 'display out of stock' configuration setting to yes but I dont want to go with this solution. I've checked elastic search query it brings every product irrespective of the stock status but although the products which are out of stock contains some values(like sku, out of stock status) but they don't contain their attribute values(like name, visibility, etc) they're empty for out of stock products. I want to know how can I get these attribute values too in my elastic search data so that I can proceed with my products,I am also open to other suggestions if any other approach can resolve the main issue of getting products which are in stock or have attribute vaue set to yes.